# Bringing durability to 0 over different time rates?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a system where a resource node has durability. They all start out at 100, but different resources have different collection times based on workers at the resource, and the resource itself.
How can I bring the durability down in relation to the timer that tracks the collection time?

```
private float timer = 0f;
public float timeToCollect = 500f;
public float durability = 100f;

void Update() {
   if(mining) {
      timer += 0.1f;
   }
}
```

So how can i reduce durability in relation to the collection timer? Basically, I want the durability to be 0 when the resource is destroyed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what have you already tried? Why didn't that work? What were you expecting to happen? What happened instead?

Comment: It might help your game to use actual units for calculating times.  For this I suggest increasing timer by Time.deltaTime in Update so that it is a reflection of an actual time unit (seconds).   The current code above shows it takes 500 units of time, time being frame rate dependent with 10 frames equal to 1 unit of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private float timer = 0f;
public float timeToCollect = 500f;
public float maxDurability = 100f;
public float durability = 100f;
int miners = 0;
void Update()
{
    timer += miners * Time.deltaTime;
    durability = maxDurability - ((timer / timeToCollect) * maxDurability); 
}
```

This is not necessarily the best way to do it, it's just to get you started.

Each time a miner is attached to the node increase `miners` count and decrease when one leaves ect. Also note that you should use `Time.deltaTime` for any timing stuff rather than just a static `0.1` as this
will keep the timing the same for computers with different frame-rates.